# Hazelcast queue configuration of dynamic queues

Tags: java, hazelcast

I have a system where dynamic queues are created. These queues are all similar in the type of messages.

I need persistence in my queues so I implemented a QueueStore. Problem is that to setup persistence I need to know the names of the queues and the names are dynamic. Is there a way to give all queues the same configuration? Even better has to have a different configuration based of some pattern of the queue name.

This is what I have so far.

```
final QueueStoreConfig queueStoreConfig = new QueueStoreConfig()
    .setFactoryImplementation(
        (name, properties) -> new GenericQueueStore(name, properties)
    );

final QueueConfig myQueueConfig = new QueueConfig()
    .setName("myQueue")
    .setQueueStoreConfig(queueStoreConfig);

final QueueConfig myQueueConfig2 = new QueueConfig()
    .setName("myQueue2")
    .setQueueStoreConfig(queueStoreConfig);


return new Config()
    .addQueueConfig(myQueueConfig)
    .addQueueConfig(myQueueConfig2);
```

Comment: Is there anything that prevents you from using config wildcards (http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/manual/html-single/index.html#using-wildcards)? PS: That obviously also works for API defined configuration :)

Comment: Thank you @noctarius !!! Don't know how I missed that. Please add your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To configure multiple data structures using the same configuration you can use the `config wildcards` and naming patterns as explained in the documentation: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/manual/html-single/index.html#using-wildcards